# Filtering an ssrs report on a column created with a lookup function

Tags: reporting-services, filtering, ssrs-2012

I have created a transaction report in ssrs reporting data from dataset1 where one of the reported columns is populated using lookup function to get data from another dataset (dataset2).  If no data is found in dataset2, the lookup function returns blank, which is what I want.  I have now been asked to filter the report so that only includes those transactions which are not included in dataset2.
I have looked for a way and tried using the lookup function in the tablix filter expression, but have read that the lookup function is done after all filtering which would indicate that this may be one of those requests that will not be fulfilled.  Have any of you tried this?

Answer (score 1):

Add a filter like this in your tablix in tablix properties / `Filters` tab:

[image]

For `Expression` use:

```
=ISNOTHING(
Lookup(Fields!FieldDS1.Value,Fields!FieldDS2.Value,Fields!FieldDS2.Value,"DataSet2")
)
```

In `Value` use:

```
=True
```

Comment: That didn't work.  It rendered an empty report.  I think this is because the filtering is processed before any lookup functions are processed.  I did get a work around by using the lookup function in the Row Visibility to Show or hide based on an expression.

Comment: @SamRoberts, I've used this before and it works ok, does your tablix have any additional filter?